# Dejar fijo el encabezado de la tabla, que no se mueva junto con el cuerpo de la tabla

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Hola necesito lograr que el encabezado de la tabla se quede fijo, que no se mueva con el resto del contenido de la tabla
El código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
#principal.table-responsive.table-hover(style='background-color:rgb(242,242,242);height:400px;')

table#tabla_listado.table.table-hover(style='font-size:12px')
  thead
    tr.noExl(style='background-color:229,229,229;background-color:rgb(229,229,229);')
      th 
        input#checks(type='checkbox',onchange='seleccion(this)')         
      th check
      th campo 1
      th campo 2
      th campo 3
      th campo 4
      th campo 5
             tr
  tbody
    each val in datos.rows
tr.active(style='background-color:243,243,243;' data-pk='#{val.pk}')
        td

input.checkpueblos(type='checkbox',value='#val.pk}',onclick='prueba();')
        td campo check
        td campo 1
        td campo 2
        td campo 3
        td campo 4
        td campo 5
```

Para el diseño de la tabla utilizo Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo la solución que estas intentando, pero podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```css
        table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

        tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            clear: both;
        }

        thead th {
            height: 40px;

            /*text-align: left;*/
        }

        tbody {
            height: 120px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        thead {
            /* fallback */
        }


        tbody td, thead th {
            width: 19.2%;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```